# How to link county and data on hover in D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to get data that I joined together to display to the correct county on hover/mouseover. Based on: https://bl.ocks.org/justinlevi/bb5b7c948177179ab65e971aeca4e59b

I have connected the data by corresponding county, but now I am stuck trying to display corresponding county data on hover.

Currently it will only display **Object:Object** with the whole data json attached on hover.

```js
[
  {
    "test_date": "2020-11-02T00:00:00.000",
    "county": "Albany",
    "new_positives": "31",
    "cumulative_number_of_positives": "3802",
    "total_number_of_tests": "1432",
    "cumulative_number_of_tests": "188977"
  },
  {
    "test_date": "2020-11-02T00:00:00.000",
    "county": "Allegany",
    "new_positives": "10",
    "cumulative_number_of_positives": "374",
    "total_number_of_tests": "227",
    "cumulative_number_of_tests": "27683"
  },
  {
    "test_date": "2020-11-02T00:00:00.000",
    "county": "Bronx",
    "new_positives": "166",
    "cumulative_number_of_positives": "56165",
    "total_number_of_tests": "7615",
    "cumulative_number_of_tests": "1034425"
  }
 
]
```

```js
// Width and height
var chart_width     =   800;
var chart_height    =   600;

var color           =   d3.scaleQuantize().range([
    'rgb(255,245,240)', 'rgb(254,224,210)', 'rgb(252,187,161)',
    'rgb(252,146,114)', 'rgb(251,106,74)', 'rgb(239,59,44)',
    'rgb(203,24,29)',   'rgb(165,15,21)', 'rgb(103,0,13)'
]);



// Projection
/*var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
    //.scale([chart_width])
    //.translate([chart_width / 2, chart_height / 2 ]);
var path = d3.geoPath(projection);
*/

//var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa().fitSize([chart_width, chart_height]);
//var path = d3.geoPath(projection);

/*var projection = d3.geoMercator()

    .scale(4500)
    .translate([chart_width / 2, chart_height / 2])

var path = d3.geoPath(projection);

//var path = d3.geoPath()
   // .projection(projection);
*/

var projection = d3.geoAlbers()
    .center([0,42.954])
    .rotate([75.527,0])
    .parallels([41,44])
    .translate([chart_width/2,chart_height/2])
    .scale(6000);

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection)



// Create SVG
var svg             =   d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", chart_width)
    .attr("height", chart_height);

// Data
d3.json('ny_covid.json').then(function(covid_data){
    color.domain([
        d3.min( covid_data, function(d){
            return d.cumulative_number_of_positives;
        }),
        d3.max( covid_data, function(d){
            return d.cumulative_number_of_positives;
        })
    ]);
    //console.log(covid_data);
    d3.json('nys.json').then(function ( nys_data ){
        nys_data.features.forEach(function(nys_e,nys_i){
            covid_data.forEach(function(z_e, z_i){
                if(nys_e.properties.name !== z_e.county){
                    return null;
                }

                nys_data.features[nys_i].properties.cumulative_number_of_positives = parseFloat(z_e.cumulative_number_of_positives)

            });
        });

        console.log(nys_data.features);

        var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0);

        svg.selectAll('path')
            .data( nys_data.features )
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr( 'd', path)
            .attr('fill', function(d){
                var num = d.properties.num;
                return num ? color (num) : '#ddd';
            })
            .attr('stroke', '#fff')
            .attr('stroke-width', 1)
            .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
                d3.select(this).transition()
                    .duration('50')
                    .attr('opacity', '.85');
                div.transition()
                    .duration(50)
                    .style("opacity", 1);
                let dee = nys_data.features;


                console.log(dee);
                div.html(dee)
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 15) + "px");
            })
            .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
                d3.select(this).transition()
                    .duration('50')
                    .attr('opacity', '1');
                div.transition()
                    .duration('50')
                    .style("opacity", 0);
                //console.log(nys_data.features)
            });
    });
});
```

```css
#chart{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    margin: 25px auto;
}


div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 28px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: .5rem;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #313639;
    border: 1px solid #313639;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NYS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some kind of identifying data attribute to each path making up the map. In this case, it could be:

```
.attr('data-county',d=>d.county)
```

*Note: I can't remember the exact path from features to county. Maybe. d.properties.county?*

Then on hover, you can use event.target.dataset.county to match up with the corresponding object in your data. And then use template literals to populate your tooltip.

It might look something like this:

```
nysData.features.forEach((el) => {
          if (
            el.properties["county"] === event.target.dataset.county
          ) {
            tooltip.innerHTML = `content you want to pull`;
          }
        });
```